# Prove that O is the middle of segment IJ

Tags: geometry

Excuse me if I get some names wrong, as I primarily study Maths in Arabic/French.
I'll try to translate the task:

Let ABCD be a parallelogram of which center (Where the two diameters cross) is point O. I is the center of the circle surrounding the triangle OBC and J is the center of the circle surrounding the triangle OAD.

1. Construct the figure
2. Prove that O is the middle of segment IJ

I already have the figure drawn [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udaMs.jpg), but I couldn't find a way to effectively prove that O is the middle of [IJ]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reflection in the point $O$ maps $A$ to $C$, $D$ to $B$ and $O$ to itself, so the circumcenter of $\triangle OAD$ is mapped to the circumcenter of $\triangle OBC$.

Comment: But that still isn't a complete answer, how do I prove O is the middle of the segment IJ?

Comment: Well, if $I$ is mapped to $J$ then $O$ must be the center of the segment $IJ$

Comment: Oh okay I got it! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The homothethy centered at $O$ with dilatation ratio $-1$ sends $I$ to $J$.  Also, you should use "circumscribing" rather than "surrounding."

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, even though I didn't understand the first sentence, especially the homothethy keyword. If you would like to, can you please simplify it more? And yeah, will use "circumscribing" from now!

Comment: My solution is the same as user133281's.  He/she used less fancy language.

Comment: Yeah I understood it now. Thank you for answering!

Comment: The circumscribing circle is also called the circumcircle. (Latin circum:(going )around; scribere:to write,draw,scribble.) I recall a teacher  mistakenly calling it the circumcised circle.